# 403 Forbidden -- Pterodactyl Web Panel Error through CentOS WebPanel

Tags: php, apache, centos, httpd.conf

I am trying to install the Pterodactyl Game Panel through CWP. I have downloaded the panel(https://pterodactyl.io/panel/1.0/getting_started.html#download-files) in my /home/domainName/public_html/panel folder and I have fallowed all the steps, but changing some configuration to the right location for this. The problem is, when I'm trying to access the web panel through my browser, it gives me "403 Forbidden You don't have permission to access this resource.". Why is that? Am I getting something wrong?

Configuration I changed from the tutorial:

chown -R domainName:DomainName /home/domainName/public_html/panel/* (turns out that CWP is using the user name for handling apache, [proof image](https://i.imgur.com/wXzkvJh.png) (hope I'm not mistaken) )

for Crontab: * * * * * php /home/domainName/public_html/panel/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1

modified /etc/systemd/system/pteroq.service to this:

```
# Pterodactyl Queue Worker File
# ----------------------------------

[Unit]
Description=Pterodactyl Queue Worker
After=redis.service

[Service]
# On some systems the user and group might be different.
# Some systems use `apache` or `nginx` as the user and group.
User=domainName
Group=domainName
Restart=always
ExecStart=/usr/bin/php /home/domainName/public_html/panel/artisan queue:work --queue=high,standard,low --sleep=3 --tries=3
StartLimitInterval=180
StartLimitBurst=30
RestartSec=5s

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Thank you so much!
(as for CWP is newly fresh installed, so it's the latest version and my OS is Alma Linux 8, if it helps)